# how to do signature in iphone app using a textfield

Tags: iphone, ios, touch

I have app in which i want that user sign the signature for contract as we normmally sign on paper so is there any way we can implement that signature user can do with finger as we normally do in documents.

Comment: @H2CO3 can you please share and help me out if you can

Comment: @Prince no need to downvote if there is answer for that you can share link instead of downvoting i have asked genuine thing.

Comment: Why downvote it is not useless question

Comment: @JdeveloperIphone Your question is being downvoted because you put no effort at all into finding your own answer to the question. A quick search would have revealed several existing answers.

Comment: @maddy i searched but i did not get anything related so it depends upone the searching also so there is no need to downvote

Answer (score 0):

You should do with the basic drawing feature available in iOS using

```
CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint
```

Then take the image and then add to the field. Its good to have an ImageView on the place where you want to sign the same.

Comment: can you please explain more and help me out

Comment: Use this [link](https://github.com/levinunnink/Smooth-Line-View). Use this to draw with your touch and then take the image of what you have drawn and then place it to your TextField or to your imageView.